# Given the sets $A, B, C, S$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

It is easy to solve for x
in $A,B,C$, but I don't understand $S=\{x∈R\mid x∈A↔x∈B−C\}$

---

Find the set S in terms of the interval. Give as an answer the sum of the finite extremes of each of the intervals that make it up.

$A=\{x∈ R / \dfrac{x}{3} ∈[−1;4]\}$

$B=\{x∈ R / (x+3) ∈[4;7]\}$

$C=\{x∈ R / \dfrac{1−2x}{2} ∈[−1;2]\}$

$S=\{x∈R / x∈A↔x∈B−C\}$

---

source: Lumbreras Editors

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the expressions leads to,

$A=[-3,12]$

$B=[1,4]$

$C=[-1.5,1.5]$

Now, $B\setminus C=(1.5,4]$(everything in $B$ that is not in $C$).

We can evaluate the condition $x\in A\iff x\in B\setminus C$ by thinking along the lines: *for what values of $x$ is it true that if it belongs to $A$ then it must belong to $B\setminus C$ and vice-versa*?

You can try to attempt before looking at the solution below.

> We can see that if $x\in A\cap(B\setminus C)$ then the above condition holds.
>  Hence $S=A\cap(B\setminus C)=(1.5,4].$